# Python 2 to Python 3 port: reading packets from virtual tunnel os.read in different formats

Tags: python

I am porting code from Python 2 to Python 3.

The code creates a virtual interface and reads packets from this interface and does a bunch of stuff with it.

What it does in Python 2 is shown as text and as an image:

```
def run(self):
    while True:

        # get IPv6 packet from virtual interface
        ipv6_string = os.read(self.virtualIf,1500)
        # Value of ipv_6 string as example
        # ipv6_string = {str} 'funny characters'
```

[image]

So it gives ipv6_string in str format with some funny characters.
The same code in Python3 gives:

```
def run(self):
    while True:

        # get IPv6 packet from virtual interface
        ipv6_string = os.read(self.virtualIf,1500)
        # Value of ipv_6 string as example
        # ipv6_string = {bytes}  b'\x00\x00\x86\xdd`\x00\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x01\xfe\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:x\xff\x02\xab\x81\xe9\xf8\xff\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16:\x00\x05\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x8f\x00\xa1\x13\x00\x00\x00\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\xff\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02'
```

[image]

So it gives ipv6_string as bytes.
I'd like ipv6_string in Python3 to be the same as Python2, however, doing decode (or str(ipv6_string, 'utf-8')) crashes and gives the error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 8: invalid start byte
"
So I'm unsure on how to proceed. I tried different codings but can't reproduce what Python2 gives me. Any help?

Comment: How so? This is for ip packets, not addresses.

Comment: oops, true. sorry. but please post your code and input as **text** and not as images. people will not be willing otherwise.

Comment: Adjusted to have both.